# Make a button clickable inside a viewCell, UIViewCollection

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, storyboard

I have created a .xib view cell view and it contains a button, label, and some text inside, how do I make the button clickable and get the details of the view ie, the label, and text?

Comment: Use the notification or make a delegate call?

Comment: I tried delegate but all the buttons, are clicked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is by adding a tag and target to the button.

```
cell.moreBtn.tag = indexPath.row
cell.moreBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showClickedBtn(sender:)), 
                       for: .touchUpInside)
```

After that, create a function that will receive the action.

```
@objc func showClickedBtn(sender: UIButton) { 
  print("Button \(sender.tag) Clicked") 
}
```

Comment: *The best **Swift** way* is a callback closure which is independent of the index path and gets rid of the Objective-C runtime bridge. Und using index paths as tags is quite cumbersome if there are sections involved and is pretty fragile if cells are being inserted, deleted or moved.

Comment: In my case is just for fetching data of a cell, with no deletion or insertion involved,